# display repeat issue with for Of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, local-storage

on this expense tracker every time I submit my form the results repeat . I'm thinking it has something to do with loop or the page refresh.

```
function addExpense(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // take the values from my form 
  // add them to my local storage to avoid losing data
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value
  let selection = document.getElementById("expenseMenu").value
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value

  const expense = {
    name,
    selection,
    amount,
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("ex_data") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("ex_data", "[]")
  }
  let array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ex_data"))
  array.push(expense)
  localStorage.setItem("ex_data", JSON.stringify(array))

  document.getElementById('expForm').reset();
  display()
}

function display() {
  let display = document.getElementById("display")
  let results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ex_data"))
  for (const info of results) {
    display.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${info.name}</td>
                <td>${info.selection}</td>
                <td>${info.amount}</td>
            </tr>`
  }
}
```

I'm guessing every time I submit the for of loop is iterating over the array from the beginning each time and repeating the list as a whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through the entire array, concatenating to the output DIV, so you never remove the old contents before adding everything again.

Instead of concatenating to the `innerHTML`, create a string with all the HTML you want, and replace the `innerHTML` with it.

```
function display() {
  let display = document.getElementById("display")
  let results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ex_data"))
  let html = '';
  for (const info of results) {
    html += `
            <tr>
                <td>${info.name}</td>
                <td>${info.selection}</td>
                <td>${info.amount}</td>
            </tr>`
  }
  display.innerHTML = html;
}
```